# Iframe DOM Problem: undefined values when accessing form field

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I've been having trouble debugging some JavaScript which normally would seem easy to fix.  I've tried several methods, some based on using a form to access fields, other ways by using getElementById.  I've also messed around with leaving in/out the name attributes in several places.

In the Iframe File, asdf_iframe.html:

```
    <form id="asdf_form" name="asdf_form" action="asdf_iframe.html">
      <input type="hidden" id="field_1">
    </form>
```

In the base file:

```
    <iframe id="asdf_iframe" name="asdf_iframe" src="asdf_iframe.html" height="50" width="50">
    </iframe>

    <script>
      function get_iframe_doc(_window,frame_id) {
        var frame_elem = _window.document.getElementById(frame_id);
        if(frame_elem.contentDocument)
          return frame_elem.contentDocument;
        else
          return frame_elem.contentWindow.document;
      }
    </script>

    <script>
      var asdf_iframe_doc = get_iframe_doc(this,"asdf_iframe"); //Profiler says this is defined
      asdf_iframe_doc.getElementById("field_1").value = 1234;   // Error Here: not defined
    </script>
```

I've tried many different methods of accessing field_1, but with no success.

Comment: Hey Skolem, both these answers solve your problem, accept one!

Comment: Oops, Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, it seems you are calling

```
asdf_iframe_doc.getElementById("field_1").value = 1234;
```

Too early. You need to call that method after the iframe finished loading its url.

Here's an attempt.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var iframe = window.frames["asdf_iframe"];
    iframe.onload = function() {
        iframe.document.getElementById('field_1').value = 1234;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script is simply running too soon. Try this instead.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var asdf_iframe_doc = get_iframe_doc(this,"asdf_iframe");
  asdf_iframe_doc.getElementById("field_1").value = 1234;
}
</script>
```

Comment: it needs to be the iframe's onload, not the outer page's onload!

Comment: Because the iframe's DOM is not ready at the same time as the window's DOM. Conceptually, you should never access a document's DOM before the corresponding window has fired the DOMReady event

Comment: @Juan - Is there a risk with your solution that the load event on the iframe will occur before the load event on the main window, so the `iframe.onload =` bit will happen too late?

Comment: It does seem plausible that the load handler for the iframe may have already run. Did not happen in the tests I ran, it seems it may  happen if your script is not in the head, but I wasn't able to reproduce it. You could work around it by testing `document.onreadystate == 'complete'`

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload, "The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading." So the iframe is guaranteed to be loaded and this should work fine.

Comment: @Juan - On the other hand, both running my code and yours seem to work fine, at least in Firefox, so there's something very curious going on with the way onload is handled in browsers to allow this to happen.

Comment: I had never seen that, I was under the impression the load event waited for images and CSS to load, I wasn't aware that it waited for iframes to load. Does that mean it also waits for images and CSS and nested frames?

Comment: @Juan - that's my interpretation, yes.

Comment: Sigh... this is why I should use jQuery.